# Is there a way to combine multiple meta annotations into one?

Tags: flutter, dart

At the moment we have a lot of classes in our codebase, who are using the same meta annotations. An example would be:

```
@autoEquatable
@immutable
@jsonSerializable
class SignInWithFacebookEvent extends LoginEvent {}
```

Is there a way in Dart where I can combine those into one? For example:

```
@event
class SignInWithFacebookEvent extends LoginEvent {}
```

This would be much simpler, and also if I would need to add/edit/remove another meta annotation from all event classes, I could just add/edit/remove one without editing hundreds of class.

**Edit:**

Even better would be inheritence of meta annotations for example:

```
@autoEquatable
@immutable
@jsonSerializable
class LoginEvent {}
```

And all of the sub classes have those annotations to. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Just like lombok's `@data` in Java that combines `@Getter`, `@Setter` and many other annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Annotations do not have language level semantics - the behavior and capabilities around metadata annotations are entirely dependent on the tools that implement those capabilities, and there is no specification for how they must treat annotations.

Some tools may work if you subclass or implement an annotation (I think angular Dart was an example that would work if you subclass the Component annotation), and other tools will not. Most tools that read metadata will not work with subclassed metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is any way of doing this natively in Dart, but there is a pub.dev package called [`super_annotations`](https://pub.dev/packages/super_annotations) that might be able to help with combining multiple annotations into one.